# Problem converting matlab code to python (numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, matlab

I have a [code](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/110755-driving-training-based-optimization) from this [paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-022-14225-7) and trying to convert it to python (numpy especially). But in this code, it has a declare that confuse me.

```
XF=[X fit'];
```

The `X` is getting from

```
function[Best_score,Best_pos,DTBO_curve]=DTBO(SearchAgents,Max_iterations,lowerbound,upperbound,dimension,fitness)

lowerbound=ones(1,dimension).*(lowerbound);                              
upperbound=ones(1,dimension).*(upperbound);                              

for i=1:dimension
    X(:,i) = lowerbound(i)+rand(SearchAgents,1).*(upperbound(i) - lowerbound(i));
end
```

and `fit` is getting from

```
for i =1:SearchAgents
    L=X(i,:);
    fit(i)=fitness(L);
end
```

My questions are

1. What it does mean?
2. How i convert it to python?

I only know that `'` meaning transpose in matlab, but i don't know the rest. I can't run this code by myself because i don't have matlab license. Also the paper's writer didn't explain it made me more confused.

I trying to run that line directly in python. Of course it doesnt work. I also try to do little modify and trying to assuming maybe it is declaring array.

```
XF = array([X, transpose(fit)])
```

And still doesnt work because it cannot combine two array with different dimension.

Btw if you asked me, the final result of this code is the best candidate solution in last iteration.

Comment: The square brackets indicate concatenation. Please provide an [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

It would have been better if you would have given the shapes of `X` and `fit`, but I guess it is something like:

```py
import numpy as np

N, M = 10, 20
X = np.random.rand(N, M)
fit = np.random.rand(M)

XF = np.concatenate([X, fit[None, :]], axis=0)
print(XF.shape)  # (11, 20)
```

You might also want to take a look at [`np.block`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.block.html):

> Matlab’s “square bracket stacking”, `[A, B, ...; p, q, ...]`, is equivalent to `np.block([[A, B, ...], [p, q, ...]])`.